# Can't override Fab disabled color material - ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Not able to change the style of the disabled button. I tried the ways discussed here https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/13779

Mui version -

"@material-ui/core": "3.8.1",

"@material-ui/icons": "3.0.1",

```
           const styles = theme => ({
              fabButton: {
                 boxShadow: 'none',
                 backgroundColor: '#fff', 
              },
              disabled: {
                 backgroundColor: '#fff', 
              },
             icon: {
                width: '20px', 
                 height: '20px', 
                 color: grey[600],
               },
            });


          <Hint title="Previous">
              <Fab 
                size="small" 
                classes={{
                  root: classes.fabButton,
                  disabled: classes.disabled
                }}
                disabled={true}
                component="div"
                onClick={onClickHandle}
              >
                <IconChevronLeft className={classes.icon} />
              </Fab>
            </Hint>
```

OR

```
           const styles = theme => ({
              fabButton: {
                 boxShadow: 'none',
                 backgroundColor: '#fff', 
                 '&:disabled': {
                      backgroundColor: '#fff',   
                 }
              },
              icon: {
                 width: '20px', 
                 height: '20px', 
                 color: grey[600],
               },
            });


          <Hint title="Previous">
              <Fab 
                size="small" 
                className={classes.fabButton}
                disabled={true}
                component="div"
                onClick={onClickHandle}
              >
                <IconChevronLeft className={classes.icon} />
              </Fab>
            </Hint>
```

In both ways `disabled` custom styles are not applying instead,  taking the default style. Any help would be appreciated.

Please check the demo here

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-rh06m

Comment: Can you please post the entire code for the component? If this is the whole code, then you need to wrap the component in the withStyles HOC when you export it.

Comment: Have done that. Will share the code via sandbox.

Comment: @lek Please check the demo, edited the question.

Answer (score 7):

The following approach works:

```
const styles = theme => ({
  fab: {
    margin: theme.spacing.unit,
    "&$disabled": {
      backgroundColor: "red"
    }
  },
  disabled:{},
  icon: {
    color: "#000"
  },
  extendedIcon: {
    marginRight: theme.spacing.unit
  }
});

function FloatingActionButtons(props) {
  const { classes } = props;
  return (
    <div>
      <Tooltip title="F">
        <Fab
          disabled
          aria-label="Delete"
          classes={{root: classes.fab, disabled: classes.disabled}}
          component="div"
        >
          <DeleteIcon className={classes.icon} />
        </Fab>
      </Tooltip>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: can you please explain the difference? why does this work?

Comment: @David The structure of the classes object is different, `disabled` is empty whereas the OP had styling specified. It's more granular to override styling with `classes` than specifying the `className` prop. More info [in the docs](https://material-ui.com/customization/components/#use-rulename-to-reference-a-local-rule-within-the-same-style-sheet) on using `&$disabled`.

Comment: I am using material-ui  for few years. I am still stuck on v3, the css class system is nice, but the in-code css implementation is screwed, totally incomprehensible. Does not work for me. Hope it is better in v4.